# How to construct such a harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Construct a harmonic function $u(z)$ in the disc $|z|<R$ for which $\lim_{r\to R} u( r e^{i\theta} )=   0$ if $ 0< \theta <\pi $ and $1$ if $\pi < \theta < 2 \pi$.

This question is from my complex analysis mid term and I couldn't solve it and so I am asking for guidance here.

I don't have much problem solving experience in harmonic functions and I don't even have a clue on how this question should be approached. So, I am looking for a solution here.

Comment: What is $r$ here, do you mean $\lim R \rightarrow$?

Comment: Did you derive the solution of the Dirichlet-Problem for the disk in class? (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel ) 
In this case you might simply try to evaluate the integral for your given function.